# C - replace if statements

Tags: c, function, reference

This code ask to user to make a choice between 0 and 4.
Based on choice , compiler call params() and pass by reference the right parameters

params() need two int :
the first is 'modula' or 'pwm' or 'period' or 'hours' or 'minutes'
the second is based on the first. Every first parameter need an address ( the second parameter)
I can pass the first parameter but I don't know how to pass the second

```
#include <stdio.h>

void params( int *value, const unsigned char eepromAddress)
{
   (*value)++;
   //do stuff
   //save to eeprom to eepromAddress
   //PSEUDOCODE
   saveToEEprom((*value),eepromAddress);
```

}

```
int main()
{
   // Parameters
   unsigned int modula=0;  // eeprom address is 50
   unsigned int pwm= 0;     // eeprom address is 51
   unsigned int period= 0;  // eeprom address is 52
   unsigned int hours= 0;   // eeprom address is 53
   unsigned int minutes= 0; // eeprom address is 54
   unsigned int *option[5];
   //user action
   unsigned int selected;
   //menu
   option[0] = &modula;
   option[1] = &pwm;
   option[2] = &period;
   option[3] = &hours;
   option[4] = &minutes; 

   //Example
   selected =  4 ;
   //Call function and pass by reference linked parameters
   params(option[selected], 50); //<-- How can I even pass eepromAddress value for each params
   //Print modified and saved parameters
   printf("%d %d %d %d %d",modula,pwm,period,hours,minutes);
}
```

---

Updated :

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct options {
   unsigned int function;
   unsigned int eeAddress;
};

void params( struct options *value)
{
   //do stuff
   value->function++;
   //PSEUDOCODE
   //saveToEEprom(value->function,value->eepromAddress); 
}

int main()
{
   //user action
   unsigned int selected;
  //menu init
   struct options menu[] = {    
    menu[0].function = 0,
    menu[0].eeAddress = 50,
    menu[1].function = 0,
    menu[1].eeAddress = 51,
    menu[2].function = 0,
    menu[2].eeAddress = 52,
    menu[3].function = 0,
    menu[3].eeAddress = 53,
    menu[4].function = 0,
    menu[4].eeAddress = 53,
   };

   //Example
   selected =  1 ;
   //Call function and pass by reference linked parameters
   params(&menu[selected]); 
   //Print modified and saved parameters
   printf("%d %d",menu[selected].function,menu[selected].eeAddress);

 }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use an array of *structures*, where each structure containing the value *and* the address?

Comment: yes it works with structure, thank you